# CentOS6.7 初回起動がされない

Tags: linux, centos

サーバーの勉強をしてみようと思い、余っているパソコンにLinuxのCentOSを入れてみたのですが、初回起動がロゴが表示される画面で止まってしまいうまくいきません。調べてみてシングルモードで起動してみると、エラーコードと思われるものが吐き出されていました。これのせいで止まっているのかと思います。Linuxについてもサーバーについても初心者なので、回答について全て理解できるかわかりませんが、何かとご助力お願いいたします。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
udev[589]: worker [609] unexpectedly returned with status 0x100
udev[589]: worker [609] faild while handling '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0'
udev[589]: worker [610] unexpectedly returned with status 0x100
udev[589]: worker [610] faild while handling '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/host0/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0'
udev[589]: worker [615] unexpectedly returned with status 0x100
udev[589]: worker [615] faild while handling '/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/FUJ02E3:00'
udev[589]: worker [616] unexpectedly returned with status 0x100
udev[589]: worker [616] faild while handling '/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A03:00'
```

使用しているパソコンは富士通のCE50Y9で、CentOSのバージョンは6.7です。dvd1のisoをダウンロードしDVD-Rにimgburnで焼き付けてインストールを試みました。

Comment: [Linux関連情報 > 動作確認情報 > 2008年春モデル FMV-DESKPOWERシリーズ TurbolinuxFUJI > FMV-DESKPOWER CE50Y9 -FMWORLD（法人）:富士通](http://www.fmworld.net/biz/fmv/annc/linux/08_Spring/dp_ce50y.html) に動作確認が記載されています。関連があるのかどうかは不明ですが、留意事項に「インストールメニューで"noacpi"を選択する必要があります」と書かれています。

Comment: RHELのナレッジに答えがありそうですがサブスクリプションが無いので見られません。どなたか類似情報持ってないでしょうか。https://access.redhat.com/ja/node/1287783

Comment: argusさんのご回答の"noacpi"ですが、https://centossrv.com/bbshtml/webpatio/2522.shtml
こちらを参考にブートオプションに"noacpi irqpoll"で起動してみましたが変わらずエラーメッセージにあることが吐かれるのみでした。

Answer (score 1):

直接の回答ではないですが、
VirtualBoxなどの仮想マシンソフトを利用して学ぶことをお勧めします。

今のご時世、ハードウェアにサーバOSを入れる業種はそれほど多くなく、
・クラウド/レンタルサーバを使用しない零細企業の何でも屋
・インフラ企業のインフラ専門エンジニア
・典型的な開発会社のインフラ特化エンジニア
　（大企業のオンプレミス要望依頼を自社内でこなす場合限定）
・情シス（自社ファイルサーバ作るぐらい）
に限られます。

現在では、
たとえ本番でもAWS、Azure、といったクラウド上で仮想マシン（VM）を用意することが半数以上を占めます。
また、ローカルの開発環境はVirtualBoxなどを入れてVMを立ち上げるのが一般的です。

VMであれば
・VMソフトを起動するPCのみでOK
・ホストゲスト間のファイル移動に、共有フォルダ機能を使って楽が出来る
・2台以上の複数台も簡単に作れ、ネットワークの学習も楽
・環境がわけわからなくなったら破棄して作り直せる
・Vagrantと連携すれば、コマンド1つでCentOSインストール済みのVMを2~3分で作れる

などのメリットもありますので、試してみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: 私は、これは回答として適格だと思います。質問者の抱えている問題に対して、何かしらの助けになりうるか（回答になりうるか）と考えると、ノーではないと思うからです。

Answer (score 0):

take88 さんがコメントした https://access.redhat.com/ja/node/1287783 は [RHBA-2015:2654](https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2015:2654) で修正されているとのことです。
kernel 起動オプションに `log_buf_len=4M` を付けて試してみるか、修正済みの udev の入っている CentOS 6.9 をインストールしてみてはいかがでしょうか。